# Feeding Numpy Arrays to CNTK LSTM Model

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, deep-learning, cntk

I'm looking to see if there is a way to feed sequence data as Numpy arrays to a text LSTM model defined in CTNK. Each instance in my dataset is a sequence of integers mapping back to words, and the length of each sequence is different. It seems like one can convert their raw text data to the CTF format and feed this data to a model by creating a `reader` function which generates mini-batches as in [this](https://www.cntk.ai/pythondocs/sequence.html) example. However, I'm wondering if there is a way to feed Numpy arrays to this same model.

Further down in this example, there is a discussion of [feeding sequences with Numpy](https://www.cntk.ai/pythondocs/sequence.html#feeding-sequences-with-numpy), which I was hoping would solve my problem. However, the example deals with sequences of images instead of variable-length sequences of words. In the case of the example, we'll end up with a tensor of `n` elements that are each `3 x 32 x 32`, and we can set up an input variable expecting these dimensions. However, in the case of sequences of words where each sequence has a different length, this example breaks down.

Any help on interop between CTNK and Numpy for text-based LSTM's / RNN's would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for:

```
x = cntk.sequence.input_variable(shape=())
```

Here is a sample little program that demonstrates how it works with a variable sequence length:

```
import numpy as np
import cntk

# define the model
x = cntk.sequence.input_variable(shape=())
z = cntk.sequence.last(x)

# define the data
a = [[1,2,3], [4,5], [6,7,8,9], [0]]
b = [np.array(i, dtype=np.float32) for i in a]

# evaluate
res = z.eval({x: b})
print(res)
```

Comment: But how to continue with LSTM thereafter ?

Comment: `x` is your input feature here for the LSTM. when you are training the LSTM, simply pass the array of variable length numpy array you have as the input data. the variable `b` is mimicking your input data. A simple example-
`
    h = Recurrence(LSTM(150))(x) 
    z = Dense(1024)(h)
`